# Importing a temperature raster layer to QGIS project

Tags: qgis

I am trying to add raster layers to depict minimum monthly winter temperatures for two counties in Ireland.  I tried importing as tiff., ADF., HDR., and bil. files.  I managed to add them in any of above formats but the results meant nothing!  How can I classify the layers so that they are colour coded when depicted and include a legend in degrees celsius?

Answer (score 1):

This works for temperatures the same way as for DEMs:

- rightclick on the layer -> `Properties`, `Style` tab
- On the left, change `Rendertype` to `Singleband pseudocolour`
- On the right, change `Mode` from `Continuos` to `Equal interval`
- Increase `Classes` to a value you wish
- Click on `Classify` and `OK`